# I can't preview post's change once they are published

Tags: publish, draft, previews

The preview function works fine when posts are just draft. The url looks like this : 
http://exemple.domain.com/blog/?p=12&preview=true

Then when I pubish my posts, let's say I want to change something and preview it, the url looks like this : http://exemple.domain.com/blog/my-article-title/?preview=true&preview_id=12&preview_nonce=514e88946a&post_format=standard

The problem is it does reflect any changes ...

I use WordPress 3.9.2 running Twenty Fourteen theme without any plugins

### EDIT

I've turn the permalink to default and it resolve the problem. But I need it to work using the pretty url ...
Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have any caching on?

Comment: @StevenJones no I don't

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the %postname% permalink and be sure that the .htaccess is modified.

If your .htaccess has blocked access you can do it manually.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

You can see more info at [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks), just look for "Using "Pretty" permalinks".

Answer (score -1):

*This is probably not the best way to do it since it wont persist after wordpress updates (but hopefully the update will correct it.*

In `wp-admin/includes/post.php` ,edit the `post_preview()` function just before returning the `apply_filters( 'preview_post_link', $url );` put the following code:

```
//ORIGINAL
//$url = add_query_arg( $query_args, get_permalink( $post->ID, true ) );

//CHANGES to make the preview work even with postname in the URL
$query_args['p'] = $post->ID;
$url = add_query_arg( $query_args, get_permalink( $post->ID, true ) );
$url = str_replace('%postname%/', '', $url); 
//END CHANGES
```

But still if there is any way to make it better ?